# Как выбрать несколько категорий для статьи

Tags: django

Имеется модель Category и Post.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    """Модель публикации статьи"""
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Черновик'),
        ('published', 'Опубликован')
    )
    rubrics = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='rubrics', verbose_name='Категория')
```

в админке при добавлении статьи появляется выбор категории.
Вопрос: как сделать добавление нескольких категорий к статье?

Comment: используйте `ManyToManyField` вместо `ForeignKey`

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался

Answer (score 0):

Вместо ForeignKey лучше использовать models.ManyToManyField, и будет вам несколько вариантов)